# Simple Query using Slite.net-PCL for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

I am trying to retrieve the database value using simple query and I am unable to do that. Below is my code.

```
 try    
 {

_connection = DependencyService.Get().GetConnection();     
var tt = _connection.Query<string>("select * from PRODUCT;");    
 }     
catch(Exception ex) { }
```

I am getting an Exception of "Row" . I am using SQLite.net-PCL library , I have the data in the database. Please help me on how can I retrieve the data from the Database using the simple query. I don't want to create a class for the table type. Any suggestions will be truly appreciated.!

Comment: what is the specific exception that is being thrown?

Comment: Its throwing an exception of "Row", just that's it.

Comment: is it happening on GetConnection or Query?

Comment: It is happening on Query.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the only column of the DataBase is of VARCHAR typ le, to match the string list return type of the Query.